# Rails clickable labels that are iteratively created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that iterates through the creation of `f.radio_button` and `f.label` where I am struggling to get the label to be clickable. My understanding of this is that the label `for` should line up with the input `id`. I'm hiding the radio icon and styling the span.

Here is my simplified form:

```
<%= form_for(@poll_response, url: responses_poll_path(@poll)) do |f| %> 
  <% @poll_options.each do |option_id, option_value| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :poll_option_id, option_id, :class => 'poll-choice-radio' %>
    <%= f.label :poll_option_id, option_id, :class => 'poll-choice-label' do %>
      <span class="poll-choice-text"><%= option_value %></span>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the HTML output:

```
<input class='poll-choice-radio' type='radio' value='1' name='poll_response[poll_option_id] 
id='poll_response_poll_option_id_1'>


<label class='poll-choice-label' for='poll_response_poll_option_id'>
  <span class='poll-choice-text'>Patriots</span>
</label>
```

I have been changing the 1st and 2nd arguments of the label in an attempt to get the label `for` to line up with the input `id`. I've tried manual strings like `"option_id" + "#{option_id}"` and `:poll_option_id_option_id`

`ruby 2.3.0p0` and `Rails 5.0.1`

Comment: Just pass in for: "poll_response_option_id_#{option_id}" in the options hash along with class:

Comment: Thank you! The multiple arguments and symbol aspects make it kind of tricky. I'll know if it works when I get this onChange submit for the form working.

Comment: Got it working. It wanted `f.label "poll_option_id_#{option_id}"` as the first argument and did not like when I tried to manually set the key of `for`. Thank you.